Looking for Manga with a similar art style as early MHA
A while back I saw this manga being recommended but I forgot to add it to my library at the time and I lost it but I am looking for it again so I can finally read it.
I don't know much about the series outside of the fact that there is a scene where a woman with what seems to be shoulder length or a bit higher hair and she was burning down a city while smiling. I am pretty sure the explanation as to why is that she and some other people like her had made rules that the people in the city must follow but they broke the rules and she burned down the city for that reason. I also believe that she has some type of unnatural ability like a superpower if I am correct.
I initially thought it was a previous work of Horikoshi because it looked like a messier and less detailed version of his art style but it wasn't.
